# OpenCV cvGetMinMaxHistValue for C++ MatND

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram

I've got a histogram in a `MatND` and I want to retrieve its max and min values. In the C version of OpenCV there is a function `cvGetMinMaxHistValue()` which does this very job, but it doesn't accept a `MatND`. What alternative do I have?

Comment: Could [this be related](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/703)? What version of OpenCV do you have? In (e.g.) OpenCV 2.3 `cv::Mat` and the ND version are already combined ([Mat](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat))

Comment: He's working with the C version, so he might not want to work with Mats. Anyways, I suppose you could manually loop through the histogram to find the min and max values. Would that be okay or are you looking for something more efficient?

Comment: I guess I'll follow Farhad's suggestion. Thank you. Could you please instruct me how to retrieve the histogram values from a histogram which is held in a MatND?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looping through the histogram is pretty easy:

```
cv::MatND hist;

[... get histogram ...]

for (int i=0; i<256; i++)
{
    float hist_value = hist.at<float>(i);
    // do stuff
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

The C++ version can be used as follows:

```
cv::MatND hist = getHistogram(image);
double min=0,max=0;
cv::minMaxLoc(hist, &min, &max, 0, 0);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your answer would be to substitute `cvGetMinMaxHistValue(`) by [See this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=minmax#cv2.minMaxLoc)`minMaxLoc`